# Android HTTP PUT request probably differs from Post, because it doesnt work?

Tags: android

Here is how I use POST and it works:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
```

And I didnt know how to use PUT, so I got this code and I changed every "Post" to "Put"
but I dont think it works:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);
httpPut.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPut);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
```

When I try updating a user's account using this implementation ot PUT I get errors from the server. - "No session. Unauthorized."
When I use Chrome's postman with the same parameters, I get no problem, so I think my PUT implementation doesnt work.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What is the question?

Comment: The question is what should I change in order for the PUT implementation to work? Some encoding perhaps?

Comment: "I get errors from the server": which ones?

Comment: No session. Unauthorized.

Comment: Does the server accept PUT? Or is this your idea?

Comment: yes they specifically told me "First log in, so we know its your user, then send us a PUT request with the account update parameters"

Comment: At the moment i have no code at hand. But if you google or search this site i'm sure you will find PUT examples.

Comment: Are you always using the same `DefaultHttpClient`? Your session should be stored in the instance, so if you use multiple instances only the one you used to login will have your session information.

Comment: If you'd like you can provide that as the answer, because it certainly helped me solve that problem! I would have never figured this out on my own. @Salem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same `DefaultHttpClient` to make all the calls, because your session information is stored in the instance object.

If you need to use different instances, you may be able to do that getting the cookies from the login request and add them in the next requests using `getCookieStore/setCookieStore`.